# Delegate set in View Controller, not maintaining in subview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, delegates, delegation

I asked this question earlier with way too much code.

The ViewController initializes a UIView chain, Controller>>View>>SubView, in the ViewController. After the SubView is initialized the ViewController is set as its delegate:

```
aSubView.delegate = self;
```

`NSLog(@"$@",aSubview.delegate),` returns the ViewController, so I know it is set.

In the SubView, `NSLog(@"$@",self.delegate),`returns random crap such a hr.lproj or a file path to the Foundation framework.

It crashes when attempting to implement any of the delegates methods, since the delegate doesn't link to the ViewController but instead randomness.

This is what the SubView.h file looks like:

```
#import "TestDelegate.h"

@interface TestSubView : UIView {

 id<TestDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (assign) id<TestDelegate> delegate;
```

EDIT: ViewController is initialized in the app delegate as such:

```
ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] init]; 
[window addSubview:controller.view];
[controller release];
```

The only other thing I added to the App Delegate, over the default is an import of the ViewController header

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible the view controller object is being released/dealloced between the two calls to NSLog?

Comment: Don't think so because since it's a chain, if the view controller was released so would everything else and I would tell since the Subview has its background set to red

Comment: But the views are also retained by the window, so if the view controller is released the views stay. Are you explicitly retaining the view controller in any way? How are you instantiating it?

Comment: Yes, as expected, you're doing nothing to retain the view controller, and it's being dealloced. Call `window.rootViewController=controller` before the release statement.